# How do I create a non-sticky footer in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I produce a footer that spans the whole width of the screen (despite screen resolution) and stays at the bottom of the page?

When I search for this I get people providing code for sticky footers (footers that hoover with the page), and saying use absolute positioning (which I hear is a no no).

A perfect example of what I mean is the one of the sites twitter bootstrap cites as an example (https://www.gathercontent.com/). On that site the footer (which looks like a hero unit or something) is always on the bottom of the page.

Comment: That site has a negative margin on the wrapper at the bottom, as well as a 100% minimum height. If you have a set height on your footer, you can do it that way, or absolutely position it. Other than that, no way around it.

Comment: @Torr3nt I tried with absolute positioning before too. The issue I had with that was it became a sticky footer on every other page

Comment: Well, yeah... if you're loading the CSS on every other page, it's going to affect every other page...

Comment: A footer that sticks to the bottom of the viewport unless the content exceeds the viewport height? Like one of Bootstraps initial examples? http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap, this example shows how you can do it. The name is misleading on the site, but it stays at the bottom of the page if there isn't much content. It also moves down the page if there is a lot of content (so doesn't stick).

The footer:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

The CSS:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/sticky-footer-navbar.css

Make sure not to forget the

```
html {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this jquery:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.footer').width($(window).width());
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.footer').width($(window).width());
    });
});
```

Make sure you have a js file though

Comment: It can be easily done with CSS. Plus that doesn't really solve his problem of putting the footer at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for something similar as I did not want the footer to hover. The footer was blocking the pull down menu elements on small mobile devices. All I did was to remove "navbar-fixed-bottom" from the footer class.

I changed

```
<div class = "footer navbar-fixed-bottom"></div>
```

to

```
<div class = "footer"></div>
```